# ffmpeg - Read raw Data instead of converting to different Format

Tags: ffmpeg

Since what ffmpeg does generally is read either an audio / image / video file of a given Codec & then converts it to a different Codec, it must have at some point hold to raw values of the media files, which:

- for Audio the raw Samples (2*44100 Samples) in case of Stereo Audio as int / float
- rgba pixel data for images (as int8 array)
- for video, array of images & linked Audio streams

How can I essentially just read those raw values & get them in Memory / on Disk in lets say C++ / Python / Java?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg is just a command line tool. The libraries behind the scene are part of the Libav* family. i.e. libavformt, libavcodec, libavtuil, swsscale, swresample, etc.

You can use those libraries directly in C or C++, or use some soft of FFI in other languages. (you can also pipe some raw formats such as y4m)

Going from a file name to a frame buffer will take a little more code than just "open()" But there are many tutorials online, and other stackoverflow questions that answer that.

Note:

> rgba pixel data for images (as int8 array)

RGBa is not very common format for video. It's usually YUV, and uasually uses sub sampling for the chroma planes. Its also usually planner, so instead of a int8 array its a array of pointers pointing to several int8 arrays